# Hard Coded SQL statements VS. Web Service to execute the queries

Tags: java, sql, database, web-services

I'm developing a Java application that communicates with a MySQL database in a server. The app should be able to read some data from an XML file and then `insert` the info read into the `database`.

I used to write `SQL Statements` directly to the Java code, but then a friend advised me to create a web service that does all the `SQL` stuff for the tool, and let the tool's only job is to read XML and send data into the web service.

My question is, does it deserve that effort? Why or Why not?

Comment: In my experience a layer is only worth it if it serves more than 3 distinct clients.  So I would not add a web service layer if there was just one website.

Comment: Probably but, it all depends on what your application does and who it is for and their associated requirements. A complete answer to an open ended question like this requires a book rather that a post on SO, even then, the answer will only be subjectively right. That makes this question effectively unanswerable.

Comment: @Andomar, one website can have many more than 3 distinct clients. Even if you intend having 1 client, there could security or connectivity reasons for hosting your data access behind a web servce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL in code is not recommended as it becomes difficult to maintain.  The application is also tightly coupled to the database structure.  Every time the database change (or you are moving to a new database) you need to make changes to your code and release again.

I don't think a web service is the correct answer here.  I would recommend you try one of the following:

1. If your application uses a lot of tables and very high throughput is not critical, use Hibernate as an ORM tool.  It has many features and can really reduce the time spent on data access.
2. If you do not have that many tables and you don't have the time to learn Hibernate, use iBatis.  It will take you 30 minutes to grasp.  It essentially allows you to put your SQL in a separate XML file, which it will read for you.  For smaller applications it is really useful and it is faster than Hibernate.
3. As a last resort, rather put your SQL in a text file(s) which you open and execute.

Answer (score 1):

How do you intend to create the webservice part? If you have the time to do, worth trying with Core Java or any Webservice framework, though I would suggest use Core java which would help to keep minimal dependency for your tool. Nevertheless, there is an ample amount of effort required to get the XML and Webservice requests in sync. My take - if it is not broken, dont fix it.